# Create a shortcut in topbar for accessing folder quickly

Tags: macos

I want to create a icon in top menu for accessing folder quickly, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's a freeware app that allows you to do this:

• [XMenu](http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/thank-you-for-downloading.html?productid=900000014)

And likely many others too.